# Black screen on 12.04 startup

Tags: 12.04, xorg, startup, error-handling, recovery-mode

Whenever I boot up Ubuntu, it shows the purple screen, then cuts to black. 
Before this happened, I was editing the Xsession file, by adding a few more lines that started up dwm and added something to it's taskbar. I also added a custom.desktop file in the xsessions folder, that launched the .xsession file.

Is there any way to fix what happened?
Or at least a way I can edit the xsessions file?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to fix what happened?

If you mean the black/purple screen, you should read this: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/169736)

> Or at least a way I can edit the xsessions file?

When your system finished booting, you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. This will bring up the tty or console. Use your credentials to log in. Then edit your file using `nano .xsession`. To save the changes, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> then close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

If you want to remove/deactivate the scripts, you can also move them:

```
mv ~/.xsession ~/xsession.bk
```

Comment: I tried editing it in recovery mode, undid changes. Still not working.

Comment: Why not just move/delete it? It's highly probable that if it wasn't a upgrade, yourself messed up the xserver.

Comment: Will the xsession file regenerate if I remove it?

Comment: Of course. If some file is missing on your login is automagically copied from the system main scripts.

Comment: Moboman the `recovery mode` is not the same as @Braiam told you. In recovery mode you should first re-mount the root and/or home partition(s) in read-write mode. Try the console way as Braiam told you.

Comment: @Moboman use the "Try Ubuntu" option. The recovery mode could not offer the capabilities to do what I asked you to do.

Comment: I don't have a bootable disk in, and it doesn't boot far enough to pull up the terminal with control + alt + F2. I'm also using WUBI, if it makes a difference.

Comment: ARG! Don't use Wubi, whatever the reason, don't use it. It's extremally buggy, and we will waste several hours figuring out what went wrong of all the things went wrong. Next time, include how you boot up in your question so everyone knows what they are dealing with. In any case, read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/169736) if you want to keep using Wubi, or just uninstall Wubi and install Ubuntu in its own partition. There's another question about how to migrate your Wubi installation, but it already have problems, so I recommend against it.